# Debugger visualiser for Qt4, MSVC 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, qt4, debuggervisualizer

I was working on a project written in C++ witch Visual Studio 2008 and Qt4.7.3 and debugging visualisation was fine.

But now I have migrated to Visual Studio 2012 and Qt4.8.5 (with Qt 1.1.8 add-in) and there is no any debugger visualisation. It shows lot of data, which actually doesn't make any sense (at least for me). Then for `QString` and `QByteArray` has been founded a solution trough https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-129
So my question is - is there a way of fixing this issue not only for `QString` and `QByteArray`, but also for other Qt types?

Thank you in advance!